# Null checking for children/grandchildren?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Apartments and Offices, each of which have Managers.

When the Manager logs on, I want to show them information related to their Apartments or Offices.

I'm trying to construct a query like the following:

```
query = Buildings.Where(i => i.Apartment.Manager.Id == User.Id);
```

But this will only work if the Manager is a manager of Apartments.  If they're not, I'll get a nullReferenceException since i.Apartment will be null for half of the buildings.

How can I check for nulls in this query to avoid the exception in the case where the manager has no Apartments, or no Buildings?

Comment: do you get an exception during or after your linq query?

Comment: During, I believe because it's iterating over Buildings looking for Building.property.subproperty, where the first property is NULL for many Buildings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query = Buildings.Where(i =>
    i.Apartment != null &&
    i.Apartment.Manager.Id == User.Id);
```

Comment: Sweet!  Didn't think it would be that easy.  Thank you.

Comment: Using your solution I get the following warning from resharper:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912830/possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable-while-checking-for-children-grandch