# Possible Multiple Enumeration of IEnumerable while checking for children/grandchildren objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following query:

```
baseQuery = Buildings.Where(
     i => i.Apartment != null 
     && i.Apartment.Manager != null 
     && i.Apartment.Manager.Name == Username);
```

I think I'm getting the error because I'm performing three separate queries here, so this operation is going to be super slow.  Any way I can optimize this check?

Edit:  I get "Possible Multiple Enumeration of IEnumerable" from resharper.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Useful information is useful!

Comment: "Possible Multiple Enumeration of IEnumerable" from resharper - I'll include that in the body.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `ContextProvider.Context.Inspections` is a `DbSet` or an `IQueryable`, this will not result in multiple enumerations of an IEnumerable.  The expression will be translated into an SQL query and executed on the server.  You can check this by putting a breakpoint after your line, and hovering over `baseQuery` to see the generated SQL.

Looks like a false positive from resharper.